# Stop conflict between mCustomscroll bar and other jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [mcustomscroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) for changing scroll bar and [scroll element](http://kadaj.github.io/tuts/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.html). When i include the `<script>` for "mcustomscroller" then scrolling of the div stops working.

Here is link to my fiddle without "mcustomscroller" --> [working link](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fx4a/3/)

Here is link to my fiddle with "mcustomscroller" --> [non working link](http://jsfiddle.net/Any7C/8/)

Please help here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting conflict with other libraries use no conflict javascript :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: i tried same but no luck,.. if u can build working fiddle then we can discuss it on